# Extend Cakephp Logged class

Tags: php, cakephp, logging, cakephp-2.3

The default Cakephp Logger ouput in the debug file is something like this :

```
2015-04-17 02:49:36 Notice: Notice (8): Undefined index: City in [/var/www/app/View/Events/view.ctp, line 57]
Trace:
include - APP/View/Events/view.ctp, line 57
View::_evaluate() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 961
View::_render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 923
View::render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 473
Controller::render() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 959
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 200
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 167
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 110
```

The thing is I don't know how the solve this because I don't know which data triggered this notice.

So I would like to know if there is a way to add the URL of the page who triggered this notice?

Comment: share the code of your view file. `/var/www/app/View/Events/view.ctp `

Comment: @u2460470 its not about the view file, i want to extend the Logged class